# Javascript AJAX request - check for success action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript that is called from a button which makes an HTTP GET request. At the moment when it encounters an error it shows a hidden div with the request error, which is all working well. Here's the script:

```js
$("#callContact1").click(function() {
  console.log('starting event');
  $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $eventURL ;?>" + eventID + "<?php echo $eventURL ;?>",
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
      $('#ajaxResponse1').html(data).show();
      var httpStatus = status;
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the event. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('httpStatus: ' + httpStatus);
      console.log('httpResponseCode: ' + httpResponseCode);
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxResponse1').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
})
```

I now need to extend this slightly to, when it is successful, show a different hidden div with a success message, e.g.:

```
$('#ajaxResponseSuccess1').html('Event Update in Progress').show();
```

I'm just not sure how to extend this script - fairly new to JS and jQuery at this point.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.done(function(data) { ...` ?

Comment: You seem to know that the error message will be shown when the `fail` callback is executed. Do you have any guess which function might be executed on success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a success function in JQuery AJAX:

Use it like so:

```
.success(function(response) {
   //DO stuff here.
})
```

A better simpler code can be like:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (e) {

            }
        });
```

View the full documentation of JQuery ajax functions is at 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

OR at

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: I didn't downvote but why suggest `success` and `error` when the OP is already using `.then` and `.fail`?

Comment: A simpler Approach for the OP as he says he is new in JQuery

Comment: If you're going to refer to documentation, why would you reference w3schools over the **actual documentation**: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/?

Answer (score 0):

You are registering two callbacks with the Ajax call. You seem to know that `fail` is executed on error. That leaves that the `.then` callback is executed on success. Just add the call there:

```
.then(function(data, status, xhr) {
  $('#ajaxResponse1').html(data).show();
  $('#ajaxResponseSuccess1').html('Event Update in Progress').show(); // <--
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $eventURL ;?>" + eventID + "<?php echo $eventURL ;?>",
      data: {},
      type: "GET",
      success : function(data)
      {
        $('#ajaxResponseSuccess1').html('Event Update in Progress').show();
      },
      error:function(xhr,status)
      {
         alert(xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
```

Using short form of ajax:

```
  $.get("www.xyz.com/abc",{eventId: eventId},callbackFunction);
```